# Input Parameter Has Only One Valid Value

Tags: function, methods, procedure, software-design

SQL Server has a system stored procedure called `sp_procoption`. It has an optional parameter `@OptionName`. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181720.aspx) documentation tells us the only value for `@OptionName` is 'startup'.

**Question**
Is there a fundamental reason (in any programming language) for a method/function/procedure to have an input parameter that only accepts a single value?  (I can probably guess the backstory for `sp_procoption`, so there's no need to address this particular example.)

Moderators: hopefully I've used proper tags.  If not, feel free to change/delete/add as appropriate.